# vb.net Export to Disk

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Im getting this error "Error in File C:\Users\Josephine\AppData\Local\Temp\Reportlist {BC17FA55-0414-4D23-B78C-311D036ADF6C}.rpt: The request could not be submitted for background processing." What seems to be the problem?
    Dim document As New ReportDocument

```
                Dim ExportPathName As String
                ExportPathName = String.Concat(New String() {"C:\Exported\", Me.cboList.Text, "\", Me.cboCust.Text})
                If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(ExportPathName) Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(ExportPathName)
                End If
                'Dim str2 As String = String.Concat(New String() {ExportPathName, "\", Controller.ExportName.ToString, ".pdf"})
                Dim str2 As String = String.Concat(New String() {"C:\test.pdf"})
                document.Load((Application.StartupPath & "\Reportlist.rpt"), CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)
                document.SetDataSource(DS)
                If System.IO.File.Exists(str2) Then
                    System.IO.File.Delete(str2)
                End If
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
                ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Exporting to PDF..Please Wait"
                document.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, str2)
                document.Dispose()
```

Comment: it generate error in exporting to pdf

Comment: Not sure if this document is relevant: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/50a6f5e8-8164-2b10-7ca4-b5089df76b33?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&36837934524320

Comment: try writing to somewhere other than to the root of the boot drive.  the app likely does not have access to that

Answer (score 0):

solve by using threading by calling a sub

sample like this
[Threading in VB.NET](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/threadingintro.htm)